# Can a method's variable be stubbed with Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest, stubbing

I'm trying to test the following method's return values. Because the result is based on the account's invoice data and new account's may not have any invoices, the method could either return a `Float`, `Float::NaN` or `Float::Infinity` depending on the specific account scenario.

I would like to test each scenario and I was thinking of stubbing some data to force the returned value, but I haven't been succesful so far.

Here's the method:

```
  def billed_amount_last_month_change
    past_month_amount = main_value # attr_reader

    previous_month_amount = account.invoices # account is attr_reader
      .where(due_date: (Time.current - 60.days)..(Time.current - 30.days))
      .where(status: %w[paid unpaid scheduled dunning refunded charged_back])
      .sum("amount_cents") / 100

    (((past_month_amount - previous_month_amount) / previous_month_amount.to_f) * 100).round(2)
  end
```

I've tried something like the following but it does not seem to work. If I put a byebug inside `#billed_amount_last_month_change` and inspect the `previous_month_amount` variable it still returns a value based on the fixtures data instead of the stubbed value.

```
test "#billed_amount_last_month_change may return a Float" do
    @account = accounts(:one)
    main_value = 3_750
    @billing_calculator = Metrics::Calculators::Kpis::Billing.new(@account, main_value)
    
    @account.invoices.expects(:sum).returns(7_500)
    expected_result = 100

    result = @billing_calculator.send(:billed_amount_last_month_change)

    assert_equal expected_result, result
end
```

Comment: This is where engineering your method to have a more focused purpose can help. Can you break out that `account.invoices` chunk into a method called `previous _month_amount`? This way you can override it as you please. Overriding a variable isn't possible.

Comment: For what it's worth, "past" and "previous" do imply roughly the same thing, which is super confusing here, especially with the mention of "last" in the method name. Three different meanings here?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I broke the method into two separate methods as suggested and it's now easier to stub the returned value. Now, and I know this was not the original question, but how would I go about asserting that the result is a NaN? I'm getting a `NameError: uninitialized constant Float::NaN` when I do something like `assert_equal Float::NaN, result.class`

Comment: Update: For now I've "tricked" it as follows: `expected_nan_result = 0 / 0.to_f` and `assert_equal expected_nan_result.to_s, result.to_s`

Comment: Remember there are constants like `Float::NAN` to avoid needing to resort to trickery. You can also check `result.nan?`